# What is the weird correspondance between subset ⊂ and implication ⇒?

Tags: logic, set-theory

As i am learning mathematical logic , I noticed similarities between the concepts of logical connecters and set operators.
Most of these made sense like how p ∧ q corresponds to P ∩ Q. Statement p ∧ q is true only when both p,q are true & similarly an element belongs to the set P ∩ Q only when it belongs to both P,Q.

But the one that puzzled me was implication. It did'nt really have an obvious counterpart in set theory and using (p ⇒ q) ≡ (¬p∨q) yielded a weird Venn diagram to say the least.
Today I came across a problem in which I was asked to represent the statement "All cats are cunning" in formal notation which I worked out to be (∀x)[Cat(x)⇒Cunning(x)]."
Now this felt very similar to how I used to use subsets to express the same idea as Ca⊂Cu:Ca={set of all cats},Cu={set of all cunning animals} during my school days.Not just this ,there are many instances where I could transform the concept of subset in quantifiers into the concept of implication.
eg (∀x∈{3,4,5,...})P(x) ≡ (∀x∈N)[(x>2)⇒P(x)]

What is this weird relationship between implication and subset ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: You should refrain to use the term "weird" so many times (especialy for things that doesn't deserve this adjective).

Comment: No "weird" at all. There is a link connecting sets and their operations ($\cap, \cup$) with the corresponding "properties" i.e. $C = \{ x \mid C(x) \}$. Thus we have the correspondence that you highlighted between $P \cap Q$ and $\{ x \mid P(x) \land Q(x) \}$.

Comment: Wrt the "similarity" between $\subseteq$ and $\to$ we have to note that there is a difference between $\cap, \cup$ and $\subseteq$: the first two are *operators* producing a set from a pair of sets, while $\subseteq$ "produces" a statement involving two sets: $P \subseteq Q$ is defined as: $\forall x (P(x) \to Q(x))$,

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3316802/how-does-one-visualize-propositional-logic (and tangentially https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2560267/why-is-the-definition-of-stronger-statement-the-way-it-is-in-logic/2560346#2560346 as well).

Answer (score 2):

The implication (if $P$ then $Q$) is true IFF the set of assignments (propositional, first order, whatever depending on the setting) which satisfy $P$ is a subset of the set of assignments which satisfy $Q$.

Answer (score 0):

1. > using (p ⇒ q) ≡ (¬p∨q) yielded a weird Venn diagram

   Okay, this is the Venn diagram (here, white space signifies that no element is contained there) that you are referring to:

   [image]

   This diagram says: If it belongs to set $A,$ then it also belongs to set $B.$
2. In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4419769/21813), I displayed the Euler diagram of $$\forall x \,\Big(A(x)\to B(x)\Big)$$ as this:

   [image]

   For your example, $A$ and $B$ denote the set of cats and cunning objects, respectively, so that “Every cat is cunning.”
3. Observe that these two diagrams correspond to each other.

Answer (score 0):

In the usual development of set theory, the expression $A\subseteq B$ is *defined* to mean $\forall x(x\in A\to x\in B)$.

Similarly, $A\cup B$ denotes the set of all $x$ satisfying $x\in A\lor x\in B$, and $A\cap B$ denotes the set of all $x$ satisfying $x\in A\land x\in B$. The set operations are in a sense just shorthand for the underlying logical operations.